# How to log flow rate in Akka Stream?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I have an Akka Stream application with a single flow/graph. I want to measure the flow rate at the source and log it every 5 seconds, like 'received 3 messages in the last 5 seconds'. I tried with,

```
someOtherFlow
  .groupedWithin(Integer.MAX_VALUE, 5 seconds)
  .runForeach(seq => 
    log.debug(s"received ${seq.length} messages in the last 5 seconds")
  )
```

but it only outputs when there are messages, no empty list when there are 0 messages. I want the 0's as well. Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try something like

```
  src
    .conflateWithSeed(_ ⇒ 1){ case (acc, _) ⇒ acc + 1 }
    .zip(Source.tick(5.seconds, 5.seconds, NotUsed))
    .map(_._1)
```

which should batch your elements until the tick releases them. This is inspired from [an example in the docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/stream/stream-rate.html#Internal_buffers_and_their_effect).

On a different note, if you need this for monitoring purposes, you could leverage a 3rd party tool for this purpose - e.g. [Kamon](http://kamon.io/introduction/get-started/).

Comment: Thanks Stefano. Complicated code for such a simple task. Kamon has no examples online (not even blogs) where they measure the rate of akka streams and output it. I'm hoping there is something simpler.

Comment: For an example of rate measurement with Kamon, check out this demo https://github.com/svezfaz/akka-backpressure-scala-central-talk/tree/master/demo . You just increment a Kamon counter for every element (see Flows.scala) that flows, and then you use a rate aggregator in your dashboard ( see the Grafana folder in the demo)

Comment: I tried the code now, it (almost always) returned 0 per 5 sec, it misses most messages. Also Kamon is not an option, because I don't have a dashboard, but just want to log it.

Comment: there was definitely a mistake in the seed function, I've fixed it and simplified it

Comment: almost correct, you have to seed with 0, instead of 1.. thanks again, works!

Comment: Assuming that your goal is to have this `Flow` emit an integer value every 5 seconds, this solution does not work (using Akka version 2.6) in the case where the source `src` produces no elements for a duration longer than 5 seconds. If `src` remains idle, nothing will be emitted from this `Flow` until another item is available from the `src`.

Answer (score 6):

Extending Stefano's answer a little I created the following flows:

```
def flowRate[T](metric: T => Int = (_: T) => 1, outputDelay: FiniteDuration = 1 second): Flow[T, Double, NotUsed] =
  Flow[T]
  .conflateWithSeed(metric(_)){ case (acc, x) ⇒ acc + metric(x) }
  .zip(Source.tick(outputDelay, outputDelay, NotUsed))
  .map(_._1.toDouble / outputDelay.toUnit(SECONDS))

def printFlowRate[T](name: String, metric: T => Int = (_: T) => 1,
                     outputDelay: FiniteDuration = 1 second): Flow[T, T, NotUsed] =
  Flow[T]
    .alsoTo(flowRate[T](metric, outputDelay)
              .to(Sink.foreach(r => log.info(s"Rate($name): $r"))))
```

The first converts the flow into a rate per second. You can supply a `metric` which gives a value to each object passing through. Say you want to measure the rate of characters in a flow of strings then you could pass `_.length`. The second parameter is the delay between flow rate reports (defaults to one second).

The second flow can be used inline to print the flow rate for debugging purposes without modifying the value passing through the stream. eg

```
stringFlow
  .via(printFlowRate[String]("Char rate", _.length, 10 seconds))
  .map(_.toLowercase) // still a string
  ...
```

which will show every 10 seconds the average the rate (per second) of characters.

*N.B.* The above `flowRate` would however be lagging one `outputDelay` period behind, because the `zip` will consume from the `conflate` and then wait for a tick (which can be easily verified by putting a `log` after the `conflateWithSeed`). To obtain a non lagging flow rate (metric), one could duplicate the tick, in order to force the `zip` to consume a second fresh element from the `conflate`, and then aggregate both ticks, i.e.:

```scala
Flow[T]
 .conflateWithSeed(metric(_)){case (acc, x) => acc + metric(x) }
 .zip(Source.tick(outputDelay, outputDelay, NotUsed)
        .mapConcat(_ => Seq(NotUsed, NotUsed))
 )
 .grouped(2).map {
    case Seq((a, _), (b, _)) => a + b
 }
 .map(_.toDouble / outputDelay.toUnit(SECONDS))
```

Comment: this seems to report the flow rate of the previous tick, i.e. the zip would always take an element from the conflate, and then wait for the tick. Right?

Comment: I've just updated the answer, for obtaining a non lagging flow rate, by duplicating the tick, which forces the zip to consume a second fresh value.

Answer (score 6):

A sample akka stream logging.

```
  implicit val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem("StreamLoggingActorSystem")
  implicit val materializer: ActorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()
  implicit val adapter: LoggingAdapter = Logging(system, "customLogger")
  implicit val ec: ExecutionContextExecutor = system.dispatcher

  def randomInt = Random.nextInt()

  val source = Source.repeat(NotUsed).map(_ ⇒ randomInt)


  val logger = source
    .groupedWithin(Integer.MAX_VALUE, 5.seconds)
    .log(s"in the last 5 seconds number of messages received : ", _.size)
    .withAttributes(
      Attributes.logLevels(
        onElement = Logging.WarningLevel,
        onFinish = Logging.InfoLevel,
        onFailure = Logging.DebugLevel
      )
    )

  val sink = Sink.ignore

  val result: Future[Done] = logger.runWith(sink)

  result.onComplete{
    case Success(_) =>
      println("end of stream")
    case Failure(_) =>
      println("stream ended with failure")
  }
```

source code is [here](https://github.com/hamednourhani/scala-playground/blob/master/src/main/scala/ir/itstar/playground/akka/stream/StreamLogging.scala).