# How does one measure throughput of Akka WebSocket stream?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I am new to Akka and developed a sample Akka WebSocket server that streams a file's contents to clients using `BroadcastHub` (based on a sample from the Akka [docs](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-dynamic.html?language=scala#using-the-broadcasthub)).

How can I measure the throughput (messages/second), assuming the clients are consuming as fast as the server?

```
// file source
val fileSource = FileIO.fromPath(Paths.get(path)

// Akka file source
val theFileSource = fileSource
  .toMat(BroadcastHub.sink)(Keep.right)
  .run
//Akka kafka file source
lazy val kafkaSourceActorStream = {

val (kafkaSourceActorRef, kafkaSource) = Source.actorRef[String](Int.MaxValue, OverflowStrategy.fail)
  .toMat(BroadcastHub.sink)(Keep.both).run()

Consumer.plainSource(consumerSettings, Subscriptions.topics("perf-test-topic"))
  .runForeach(record => kafkaSourceActorRef ! record.value().toString)
}

def logicFlow: Flow[String, String, NotUsed] = Flow.fromSinkAndSource(Sink.ignore, theFileSource)

val websocketFlow: Flow[Message, Message, Any] = {
  Flow[Message]
    .collect {
      case TextMessage.Strict(msg) => Future.successful(msg)
      case _ => println("ignore streamed message")
    }
    .mapAsync(parallelism = 2)(identity)
    .via(logicFlow)
    .map { msg: String => TextMessage.Strict(msg) }
  }

val fileRoute =
  path("file") {
    handleWebSocketMessages(websocketFlow)
  }
}

def startServer(): Unit = {
  bindingFuture = Http().bindAndHandle(wsRoutes, HOST, PORT)
  log.info(s"Server online at http://localhost:9000/")
}

def stopServer(): Unit = {
  bindingFuture
   .flatMap(_.unbind())
   .onComplete{
    _ => system.terminate()
      log.info("terminated")
  }
}
//ws client
def connectToWebSocket(url: String) = {
 println("Connecting to websocket: " + url)

 val (upgradeResponse, closed) = Http().singleWebSocketRequest(WebSocketRequest(url), websocketFlow)

 val connected = upgradeResponse.flatMap{ upgrade =>

   if(upgrade.response.status == StatusCodes.SwitchingProtocols )
  {
    println("Web socket connection success")
    Future.successful(Done)

  }else {
     println("Web socket connection failed with error: {}", upgrade.response.status)
     throw new RuntimeException(s"Web socket connection failed: ${upgrade.response.status}")
   }
}

connected.onComplete { msg =>
    println(msg)
 }         
}
def websocketFlow: Flow[Message, Message, _] = { 
 Flow.fromSinkAndSource(printFlowRate, Source.maybe)
}

lazy val printFlowRate  =
 Flow[Message]    
  .alsoTo(fileSink("output.txt"))
  .via(flowRate(1.seconds))
  .to(Sink.foreach(rate => println(s"$rate")))

def flowRate(sampleTime: FiniteDuration) =
 Flow[Message]
  .conflateWithSeed(_ ⇒ 1){ case (acc, _) ⇒ acc + 1 }
  .zip(Source.tick(sampleTime, sampleTime, NotUsed))
  .map(_._1.toDouble / sampleTime.toUnit(SECONDS))

def fileSink(file: String): Sink[Message, Future[IOResult]] = {
 Flow[Message]
  .map{
    case TextMessage.Strict(msg) => msg
    case TextMessage.Streamed(stream) => stream.runFold("")(_ + _).flatMap(msg => Future.successful(msg))
  }
  .map(s => ByteString(s + "\n"))
  .toMat(FileIO.toFile(new File(file)))(Keep.right)
}
```

Comment: Related hint, the way you build the file source is very inefficient (and leaks file handles). Please use the built in file sources in the FileIO object as documented in the akka docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could attach a throughput-measuring stream to your existing stream. Here is an example, inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41980353/how-to-log-flow-rate-in-akka-stream/41984865#41984865), that prints the number of integers that are emitted from the upstream source every second:

```
val rateSink = Flow[Int]
  .conflateWithSeed(_ => 0){ case (acc, _) => acc + 1 }
  .zip(Source.tick(1.second, 1.second, NotUsed))
  .map(_._1)
  .toMat(Sink.foreach(i => println(s"$i elements/second")))(Keep.right)
```

In the following example, we attach the above sink to a source that emits the integers 1 to 10 million. To prevent the rate-measuring stream from interfering with the main stream (which, in this case, simply converts every integer to a string and returns the last string processed as part of the materialized value), we use [`wireTapMat`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.5/akka/stream/scaladsl/Source.html#wireTapMat[Mat2,Mat3](that:akka.stream.Graph[akka.stream.SinkShape[Out],Mat2])(matF:(Mat,Mat2)=%3EMat3):FlowOpsMat.this.ReprMat[Out,Mat3]):

```
val (rateFut, mainFut) = Source(1 to 10000000)
  .wireTapMat(rateSink)(Keep.right)
  .map(_.toString)
  .toMat(Sink.last[String])(Keep.both)
  .run() // (Future[Done], Future[String])

rateFut onComplete {
  case Success(x) => println(s"rateFut completed: $x")
  case Failure(_) =>
}

mainFut onComplete {
  case Success(s) => println(s"mainFut completed: $s")
  case Failure(_) =>
}
```

Running the above sample prints something like the following:

```
0 elements/second
2597548 elements/second
3279052 elements/second
mainFut completed: 10000000
3516141 elements/second
607254 elements/second
rateFut completed: Done
```

If you don't need a reference to the materialized value of `rateSink`, use `wireTap` instead of `wireTapMat`. For example, attaching `rateSink` to your WebSocket flow could look like the following:

```
val websocketFlow: Flow[Message, Message, Any] = {
  Flow[Message]
    .wireTap(rateSink) // <---
    .collect {
      case TextMessage.Strict(msg) => Future.successful(msg)
      case _ => println("ignore streamed message")
    }
    .mapAsync(parallelism = 2)(identity)
    .via(logicFlow)
    .map { msg: String => TextMessage.Strict(msg) }
  }
```

`wireTap` is defined on both `Source` and `Flow`.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable feedback. I updated the code with web socket client that measure rate (events/sec) and also write to a file.                    I am using akka-kafka-stream source to consumer data and send to web socket clients. The max rate i got was 35k/sec which seems pretty low considering the benchmark for using akka-kafka plain consumer is 944,746 mgs/sec. Here is the bencmark link,  https://softwaremill.com/benchmarking-akka-stream-kafka/

Comment: Is there anything else I need to do to improve the throughput? Appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Where I last worked I implemented a performance benchmark of this nature.

Basically, it meant creating a simple client app that consumes messages from the websocket and outputs some metrics. The natural choice was to implement the client using akka-http client-side support for websockets. See:

https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/client-side/websocket-support.html#singlewebsocketrequest

Then we used the micrometer library to expose metrics to Prometheus, which was our tool of choice for reporting and charting.

https://github.com/micrometer-metrics

https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_meters